# Docker - Ubuntu - Nginx - MariaDB - Connection refused

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, nginx, docker

Im trying to setup a docker container on OSX with Docker - Ubuntu - Nginx - MariaDB to run a Laravel App

My docker settings are:

```
version: "2"
services:
  nginx:
      build:
          context: ./nginx
      ports:
          - "8080:80"
      volumes:
          - ./app:/var/app
  fpm:
      build:
          context: ./fpm
      volumes:
          - ./app:/var/app
      expose:
          - "9000"
      environment:
          - "DB_HOST=db"
          - "DB_DATABASE=laravel_db"
  db:
      image: mariadb
      ports:
          - "33061:3306"
      environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=laravel_db
      volumes:
          - ./database:/var/lib/mysql
```

And the 2 docker files:

```
FROM nginx
ADD ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
CMD service nginx start
```

---

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common language-pack-en-base \
    && LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y php7.0 php7.0-fpm php7.0-mysql mcrypt php7.0-gd curl \
       php7.0-curl php-redis php7.0-mbstring sendmail supervisor \
    && mkdir /run/php \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

RUN sed -i -e 's/listen = \/run\/php\/php7.0-fpm.sock/listen = 0.0.0.0:9000/g' /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf \
    && sed -i -e 's/;daemonize = yes/daemonize = no/g' /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf

WORKDIR /var/app

EXPOSE 9000

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

So far so good. I can access the Laravel App homepage as **localhost:8080** and use Sequel Pro to access the MySQL DB.

But when access to the Laravel route that requires DB query, it returns "Connection refused"

Then I create a raw PHP file to make a DB connection test:

```
$link = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'root', 'laravel_db', 33061);
if(!$link) {
    die('failed to connect to the server: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

And I get connection refused error as well.

I tried using 127.0.0.1 and localhost but no hope.

Tried to google it but most answers are about ports are not published...

Thanks

Comment: Could you try ```$link = mysqli_connect('db', 'root', 'root', 'laravel_db', 33061);```?

Comment: No, Im using exactly that code and i get connection refused

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `link` directive to connect various docker containers when using docker-compose. Ie, if you want to have docker container A communicate with docker container B, they need to be 'linked'

[docker-compose documentation on links](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/links)

Comment: I added the `links` in `nginx` service but still getting connection refused.

Tried: links: fpm or db

Comment: It looks like youre using v2 of docker-compose so it actually wouldn't be a 'link directive'. You'll want to use 'depends_on: db' or whatever you'd like to connect to. The key thing is that the host will be 'db' (or whatever the container is named), it won't be 'localhost' / 127.0.0.1

Comment: I replace it with `depends_on:  - db  - fpm` but still. Do I need to rebuild or do something prior to `docker-composer up -d` ?

Comment: You don't need to rebuild the image; docker-compose just sets up and runs containers. Your problem is most likely that you are connecting to *localhost* instead of *db* (from your code `$link = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'root', 'laravel_db', 33061);`). The name of the host will be `db`; it won't be `127.0.0.1`. From within the container you should do `getent hosts db` and you should see a private IP address. If you see this private IP address it means your current container is linked to the `db` container. If you don't see the address it means the containers aren't linked.

Comment: I can see the IP address of the `db` but still cannot connect.

I tried the dbhost with: db, localhost, 127.0.0.1 and even the db private IP address. Still not work